# Taylor (Maclaurin) Series remainder for ${\rm sin}\ (x)$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

So I just finished doing this problem and I think the solution I got is wrong, it seems a bit too large. According to my calculations, I need 36 terms. I fear I've made a mistake and I would really appreciate it if anyone could confirm or disprove my suspicions.

Find the smallest number N terms needed to make the remainder

$$R_{N+1}(x) = {\rm sin}\ (x) - \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{ D^{k}f(0)}{k!} x^{k}$$

have $|R_{N+1}(x)| < 10^{-6}$ throughout the subinterval $-10 \leq x \leq 10$.

The general gist of my calculations is as follows: Using the formula I'm given for the remainder,

$|R_{N+1}(x)| = \frac{f^{N+1}(x)}{(n+1)!} \cdot x^{N+1}$ but on any interval [-R,R], there

is a common bound $|D^{k}f| \leq M_R$   $\forall k$ and $|x| \leq R$ which yields the

remainder estimate, $|R_{N+1}(x)| \leq \frac{M \cdot R^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}$   but,

$|D^k(sin(x))| \leq 1 \implies M = sup|D^k(sin(x))| = 1$. Similarily, given the interval 
$-10 \leq x \leq 10$,

$R = 10.$ So, substituting we get $\frac{10^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}$ so, we want an N such that

$\frac{10^{N+1}}{(N+1)!} < 10^-6$ so, $(N+1)! > 10^{N+7}$.

I apologize if formatting is poor, not very familiar with LaTeX.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd show your calculations.  Also, it is spelled "Maclaurin" - fixing this will make it easier for people to find this question by searching.

Comment: Suppose I should've thought of that. I'll add them now. Bear with me, I am definitely not LaTeX proficient.

Comment: Yes, you need a lot of terms. For that reason, one would not compute that way.

Comment: What would a more efficient way to compute it be? Also fixed spelling, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact $36$ is exactly right.  $R_{35}(10) \approx 8.997 \times 10^{-6} $
while $R_{36}(10) \approx 6.804 \times 10^{-7}$.

---

Comment: Thank you very much! I just added my calculations but you beat me to the punch. Much appreciated.